# how to add auto-increments on non primary key column, but their is still another column which i want to set as primary key

Tags: php, laravel

i'm creating a database for school management in laravel.. i'm stuck in students table where i want to set primary key as "reg_no" column without auto-incrementing and still want the "id" column as auto-incrementing, i tried "protected $primaryKey" and "public $incrementing" but these properties does not solve the problem..

after did this, my db still point "id" column as primary key..

Here are some screen shots:

model:

[image]

table/migration:

[image]

Database in Xampp:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the database migration for the students table?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand, but both migration table and migrated database to xampp pics are added in my question

Answer (score 0):

Add this in 'up' method of students migration file

```
Schema::table('students', function(Blueprint $table) {

    // Remove the primary key
    $table->dropPrimary("id");

    // Set the actual primary key
    $table->primary(array("reg_no"));
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to wrap the column name in an array since Laravel will do this for you. Also, you will need to index the `id` column before you remove it as the primary key otherwise an exception will be thrown since the auto increment column must be a `key`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help Ross, i really got this error that you mentioned lol, it's because i don't know how to index. please give an example how i index my id column. my table is "students"... Thanks

Comment: @waqarfazal92 `$table->index('id');`